# Bootstrap intervenes with datatable css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

## using datatables only

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
<div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="width: 7548px; padding-right: 17px;">
<table class="display dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 7548px;">
```

---

## After using bootstrap

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
<div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 7565px;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="width: 4401px; padding-right: 17px;">
<table class="display dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 4401px;">
```

So I had to revert back the previous css. I also need bootstrap since there is other css that depends upon it, but bootstrap also changed the datatables' CSS. Temporary solution was

```
$('.dataTables_scrollHead').css('width','100%');
$('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css('widht','7548');
$('.dataTable, .display').css('width','7548');
```

Is there any solution so that bootstrap won't touch my datatable CSS ?
Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you read through this: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

Comment: Ya I looked into http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 as well, but I am not quite sure how to relate my issue with changes made in Booststrap 2
###  I am using Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: Where you append your table know there you need to change like this         style="position:relative; overflow:scroll;" And comment scrollY,             var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
      "dom": '<"top"if>t<"bottom"><"clear">',
      "bSort": false,
      "paging": false,
      //"scrollY":"450px"
     } );

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, I have blogged some modifications may help:

http://devblog.rayonnant.net/2013/09/bootstrap-3-datatables-paging.html

My example is based on the Bootstrap 2 modifications on the datatables.net website, just modified to work with Bootstrap 3's CSS and form structure.

Answer (score 0):

Better Solution was given a unique class name to the data table and customize it,

Follow this:

1. don't use 3000px width or something, use measurement in percentage.so can achieve responsiveness behave.
2. maximum avoid the inline CSS styling.